# Como obter a separação de linha do sistema

Tags: javascript

Alguns sistemas operacionais (i.e.: Windows e BSD) gostam de quebrar as linhas com `Carriage Return` (CR) seguido de `Line Feed` (LF), ou `\r\n`.

Já GNU/Linux, OS X e outros Unix-like costumam quebrar só com LF (`\n`).

Existe alguma forma, em Javascript, de se obter o caractere de quebra de linha do sistema cliente? Alguma API do HTML 5 ou qualquer coisa que me permita obter isso sem apelar para a leitura do cabeçalho *user agent* de uma requisição, a fim de verificar o sistema operacional?

Comment: Não encontrei uma resposta, mas não entendi o que quis dizer com "apelar para a leitura do cabeçalho *user agent* de uma requisição". Que eu saiba, essa informação está disponível via [`window.navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator) (e a partir daí `oscpu`, `platform` ou `userAgent` - o que for mais confiável/fácil de interpretar), podendo ser usada pra inferir o tipo de quebra de linha. Aliás, só de curiosidade, o que você pretende fazer de posse dessa informação?

Comment: Vou verificar o tipo de quebra de linha do usuário para montar um texto e fazer uma requisição pro servidor. Da requisição será gerado um arquivo e eu vou redirecionar o usuário para esse arquivo. Gostaria que o arquivo tivesse as quebras do sistema do usuário.

Comment: Por que o fato da quebra de linha ser com CR ou LF é importante nesse caso?

Comment: @gabrielhof queria que as quebras ficassem direitinhas nos editores de texto (amigos meus OS X'istas reclamam quando tem \r, eu Windows'ista reclamo quando não tem), mas confesso que há também um misto de curiosidade acadêmica com pedância de minha parte.

Comment: Esse texto vai ser gerado e exibido no browser? Quanto ao servidor, o que você faz com o texto nele?

Comment: Como curiosidade, é interessante. Pra uso prático, não consigo imaginar. Ex: Um usuário com Linux grava a saída num pendrive, entrega o pendrive para um amigo que usa Windows, que é quem vai precisar do texto. Acabamos de perder todo o esforço de se basear no OS da requisição para decidir o formato de saída (lembrando que se for pra usar com http apenas, a quebra de linha faz parte do padrão da especificação, e não do OS).

Comment: @gabrielhof uso como input pra fazer uma requisição que monta um arquivo, e depois forço o download do arquivo.

Comment: Bem, nesse caso, acho melhor tu padronizar só o `\n` devido ao caso que o @Bacco citou.

Comment: Estou chegando a essa conclusão também. Mas ainda queria saber se é possível obter o separador de linha, só por curiosidade mesmo agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na especificação do ECMA a [seção 7.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3) apenas define a gramática e os possíveis tokens reconhecidos como quebra de linha.

Como não há uma forma exata de descobrir os caracteres da quebra de linha. Deixo registrado uma heurística para detecção do estilo de quebra de linha:

```
function getLineBreakSequence() {
    var div, ta, text;

    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<textarea>one\ntwo</textarea>";
    ta = div.firstChild;
    text = ta.value;

    return text.indexOf("\r") >= 0 ? "\r\n" : "\n";
}
```

Segundo **T.J. Crowder** nessa [resposta do SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833269/javascript-platform-independent-line-separator/6833299#6833299), essa função funciona porque os browsers que usam o `\r\n` fazem a conversão *on-the-fly* do `\n` quando fazem o *parsing* da string HTML.

**Além disso é necessário reforçar que os resultados podem variar para um mesmo SO. Porque browsers diferentes fazem coisas diferentes.**

É possível testar no [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aruzuz).

Answer (score 3):

Dá pra fazer algo bem próximo do que você quer sem usar Javascript. O cabeçalho HTTP [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) inclui informações sobre o browser e sistema operacional do seu cliente e seu servidor pode olhar isso quando receber o formulário do cliente. Não é algo 100% certeiro, já que o valor do cabeçalho User-Agent é configurável pelo usuário, mas ao mesmo tempo não acredito que exista alguma forma 100% certeira de saber o OS do cliente.

É claro, uma outra possibilidade é adicionar um campo extra no seu formulário e perguntar pro cliente que tipo de quebra de linha ele prefere :P

Answer (score 1):

Como aplicação prática, imagino que a ideia seja identificar a quebra de linha (line ending) pelo S.O. para poder trocar por uma tag HTML, por exemplo, mostrar em tempo real a saída de um campo textarea (assim como acontece no StackOverflow).

Você pode usar uma expressão regular que identifique o `\n` (usado pelo *NIX) ou `\r\n` (usado pelo Windows).

```
htmlstring = stringContainingNewLines.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```